# Solution to this hypergeometric function-beta function product integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, hypergeometric-function, beta-function

I am trying to calculate the energy of a system, and have reduced part of it down to an integral;
$$
\int^\infty_0 \frac{ t^{\frac{5}{\alpha}-7}}{(1+t)^8}\space_2F_1(1,\frac{3}{\alpha}-6;\frac{3}{\alpha}-5;-t) \space dt,
$$
in which $2 \leq \alpha \leq 4$.
I'm not sure how to approach this problem, and I am not particularly well versed (if at all) in hypergeometric functions, so if anyone can give me some advice or help me solve this, I would be very grateful!

Edit: The first term in the integral, before the hypergeometric function, is easily integrable. I know that hypergeometric functions integrate pretty easily, also. My problem is the product of the two here.

Edit 2: Perhaps I should add, the integral comes from first solving
$$
\left(\frac{3}{\alpha}-6\right)\int^\infty_0 \frac{ t^{\frac{2}{\alpha} -1}}{(1+t)^8}\left(\int_0^t \frac{t'^{\frac{3}{\alpha}-7}}{(1+t')}dt'\right)dt.
$$

Comment: A closing ")", a $dt$, limits of integration are missing in your last formula. It is perhaps $1+tt'$ and not $1+t'$.

Comment: @Gary there was indeed missing limit of integration on the second integral in the last formula too, it's from $0$ to $t$ - thanks.

Comment: The integral diverges because of how fast the integrand diverges as $t \to 0^+$.

Comment: The $t'$-integral is convergent if and only if $\text{Re}(\alpha)<\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
\begin{align*}
& \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{t^b }}{{(1 + t)^c }}{}_2F_1 (1,a;a + 1; - t)dt} = \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{t^b }}{{(1 + t)^{c + 1} }}{}_2F_1\!\left( {1,1;a + 1; \frac{t}{{1 + t}}} \right)dt} 
\\ &
 = \Gamma (a + 1)\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  { \frac{{n!}}{{\Gamma (a + 1 + n)}}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{t^{b + n} }}{{(1 + t)^{c + 1 + n} }}dt} } 
\\ &
 = \Gamma (a + 1)\Gamma (c - b)\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  { \frac{{n!\Gamma (b + 1 + n)}}{{\Gamma (a + 1 + n)\Gamma (c + 1 + n)}}} 
\\ &
 = \frac{{\Gamma (b + 1)\Gamma (c - b)}}{{\Gamma (c + 1)}}{}_3F_2 (1,1,b + 1;a + 1,c + 1; 1)
\end{align*}
provided that $ - 1 < \text{Re}( b) < \min(\text{Re}(c),\text{Re}(a)+\text{Re}(c)-1)$.

Comment: Note that $b=5/\alpha-7$ does not satisfy $-1 < b$ when $\alpha \ge 2$.

Comment: @GEdgar In that case, the OP has integrability problems at $t=0$.

Comment: Quite right.  The OP specifies $2 \le \alpha \le 4$.

Comment: If it's any help, this is a gravitational potential energy of a spherical distribution of mass that's being calculated - due to physical constraints, everything at t = 0 should be 0 as it's non-existent.

Comment: @FairyLiquid It does not help. Look at my comment to your question.

Comment: So I'm guessing there's no way of solving this?

Comment: @FairyLiquid With your conditions on $\alpha$, your integral is divergent.

Comment: So it would be solvable for $1 \leq \alpha \leq 2$, or would it have to be $\lt 2$?

Comment: Sorry I meant $\alpha<\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I have re-done everything with a different approach and arrived at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4432075/solution-to-this-beta-function-integral-within-an-integral-continued), maybe this will work better?

Comment: @Gary, how would I move from $\space_2F_1(1,a;a+1;-t)$ to $\space_2F_1(8,a;a+1;-t)$? Sorry to keep bothering!