# Solution to this beta function integral-within-an-integral (Continued)

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, hypergeometric-function, beta-function

Continuing on from my earlier post, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4431905/solution-to-this-hypergeometric-function-beta-function-product-integral?noredirect=1#comment9276573_4431905), I have re-evaluated all the work-up to the integral and managed to re-formulate everything to be slightly different. Now, the aim is to solve
$$
I = \int_0^\infty \frac{t^{\frac{3}{\alpha}-1}}{(1+t)^8}\left(\int_0^t
\frac{t'^{\frac{2}{\alpha}-1}}{(1+t')^8}dt'\right)d t.$$
Once again, we have the condition that $2 \leq \alpha \leq 4$, where $\alpha$ is real. I'm not sure if the same problem stands that the inside integral diverges if $\alpha < 1/2$, as in my previous question or if this has managed to help somehow as the exponent is different.

Thanks!

Edit:

This once again can be written out as the integral of a hypergeometric function,
$$
I = \frac{\alpha}{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{t^{\frac{5}{\alpha}-1}}{(1+t)^8}\space_2F_1(8,\frac{2}{\alpha};\frac{\alpha+2}{\alpha};-t) \space dt.
$$

Comment: It seems that you struggle with the understanding of when integrals converge. Note that the $t'$-integrand behaves like $t'^{\frac{2}{\alpha } - 1}$ near $t'=0$. But $
\int_0^\varepsilon  {t'^{\frac{2}{\alpha } - 1} dt'}  = \left[ {\frac{\alpha }{2}t'^{\frac{2}{\alpha }} } \right]_0^\varepsilon$ exists only if $\frac{2}{\alpha}>0$, i.e., $\alpha>0$. I will come back to your main question later, it should be doable the same way as the other one.

Comment: @Gary you're right - we didn't get much of an opportunity to learn this in my physics course. This has helped, though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\operatorname{Re}(a) > 0$ and $- 1 < \operatorname{Re}(b) < \min (\operatorname{Re}(c)+7,\operatorname{Re}(a) + \operatorname{Re}(c) - 1)$, then
\begin{align*}
& \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{t^b }}{{(1 + t)^c }}{}_2F_1 \left( {8,a;a + 1; - t} \right)dt}  = \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{t^b }}{{(1 + t)^{c + 8} }}{}_2F_1 \!\left( {8,1;a + 1;\frac{t}{{t + 1}}} \right)dt} 
\\ & = \frac{{\Gamma (a + 1)}}{{7!}}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{\Gamma (8 + n)}}{{\Gamma (a + 1 + n)}}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{t^{b + n} }}{{(1 + t)^{c + 8 + n} }}dt} } 
\\ & = \frac{{\Gamma (a + 1)\Gamma (c - b + 7)}}{{7!}}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{\Gamma (8 + n)\Gamma (b + 1 + n)}}{{\Gamma (a + 1 + n)\Gamma (c + 8 + n)}}} 
\\ & = \frac{{\Gamma (b + 1)\Gamma (c - b + 7)}}{{\Gamma (8 + c)}}{}_3F_2 (1,8,b + 1;a + 1,c + 8;1).
\end{align*}
In your case $a=\frac{2}{\alpha}$, $b=\frac{5}{\alpha}-1$, $c=8$ and $2\leq\alpha\leq 4$ fulfill the conditions.

Comment: I appreciate this a lot, and will work through it today. Is there any specific resource you might recommend for me to read to understand how to manipulate 2F1 like this? I think I'll be using these a lot with this current project.

Comment: See https://dlmf.nist.gov/15 in general and especially https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.8

Comment: @FairyLiquid If you look for lecture notes on google, there’s plenty of good stuff in the first few pages of results. I particularly like this set of notes for beginners: https://homepage.tudelft.nl/11r49/documents/wi4006/hyper.pdf